# AS3: Refer to a property of an object when both the objects name and the property name aren't known 'till runtime?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, object, eval

Because AS3 does not include `eval()` I am confused on how to access objects dynamically.

I want to refer to a specific property of an object but the name of the object and the property's name are not know until runtime.  I've tried my best to figure it out, but I'm at a loss. Here is some code to illustrate the problem:

### In the following code, we can access properties like 
this: `trace(ObjectName.PropertyName);` 
...

```cs
//object definitions 

var myObj1:Object = {

    myProp1 : "cat",
    myProp2 : "dog",
    myProp3 : "fish"
};

var myObj2:Object = {

    myProp1 : "carrot",
    myProp2 : "potato",
    myProp3 : "celery"  
};

//tests
trace( myObj1.myProp2 ); //dog
trace( myObj2.myProp3); //celery
```

### But I want to access them dynamically w/ two different iterators like
this: `trace( eval("myObj" + i +".myProp" + j));`

## code I've tried:

```cs
//example iterators

var i:int = 2;
var j:int = 3;
```

```cs
trace( "myObj"+i+".myProp"+j); //outputs expected string, myObj2.myProp3
```

```cs
trace( getChildByName(["myObj" +i]).getChildByName(["myObj" +j]) );  //error
```

```cs
trace( this["myObj" +i].this["myProp" +j] ) //error
```

```cs
var currObj:String = getChildByName(["myObj" +i]);
var currProp:String = getChildByName(["myProp" +j]);

trace (currObj.currProp); //lots of errors
```

**Thanks For the Help :)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with your third attempt using the array access method:

```
trace( this["myObj" + i]["myProp" + j] ) // no error
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I gave up a tad early.
 
Question: Can you explain to me what "this" means in this situation? Not quite sure I understand what its doing as compared to how I understood the keyword to be used.

Comment: this refers to the current scope which is effectively an associative array containing all the properties of that object. myProp[j] is a property of a different scope so needs to be accessed via that scope rather than via this. Think of it as a multi-dimensional array if that helps.

Comment: with that definition for "this" why does it solve the current situation?  trace(["myObj" + i]);  would not work but when the word this is added, what is inside the parenthesizes is actually evaluated....why does that happen?

Comment: If you remove the this before, the compiler will create a new array.
var myArray:Array = ["hello"];

Answer (score 1):

The getChildByName is only for display list. You can use [] in object.

Change this

```
trace( this["myObj" +i].this["myProp" +j] ) //error
```

To this

```
trace( this["myObj" +i]["myProp" +j] ) //Working
```